# The implementation of variable-to-factor and factor-to-variable messages?

Tags: regression, graphical-model, graph-theory, conditional-random-field

I read [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-a-linear-chain-conditional-random-field-crf-in-pytorch-16b0b9c4b4ea) on the implementation of CRF and got to know that the normalization is the sum-product message passing. And I also [know that](https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/inference/jt/) there are two types of messages on factor graph:

Variable-to-factor messages(left) and factor-to-variable messages(right):

[image]

But it seems difficult for me to relate the message passing to the implementation of the CRF. Since logistic can be seen as a simplified CRF could anyone please help explain what the two messages are in the logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

After reading [Factor Graphs and The Sum-product Algorithm](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/factorgraphs.pdf) by Kschischang I learned that the variable-to-factor messages are just multiplication because it does not do anything about variable elimination; while the facter in factor-to-variable is like one step of sum-product operation. All variables summed up are eliminated and the message passes hence.

The logistic regression has only one step of sum-product(actually no connections between variables) and hence the triplet relations just cannot form.